# how to transforming yaml file to a list with complex object generic

Tags: spring, yaml, snakeyaml

my yaml like this:

```
- code: code1
  type: REST
  base-url: https://api.test1.com/api/v1
  endPoints:
    - type: BATCH
      path: /transmissions
      method: POST
      content-type: application/json
      headers: [{key: Authorization, expression: '#root.apiKey'}]
      dependencies: []
      params:
        - key: campaign_id
          source: campaign_id
        - key: subject
          source: subject
- code: code2
  type: SAAS
  base-url: https://api.test2.com/api/v1
  endPoints:
    - type: ONE
      path: /transmissions2
      method: GET
      content-type: application/json
      headers: [{key: Authorization, expression: '#root.apiKey'}]
      dependencies: []
      params:
        - key: campaign_id
          source: campaign_id
        - key: subject
          source: subject
#
...
```

java generic class:

```
@Data
public class MappingField {
    private String code;
    private ServiceType type;
    @JsonProperty("base-url")
    private String baseUrl;
    private int port;
    private List<EndPoint> endPoints;
    private Map<String, EndPoint> endPointMapByType = new HashMap<>();

    @Data
    public static class EndPoint {
        private EndpointType type;
        private String path;
        @JsonProperty("content-type")
        private String contentType;
        private HttpMethod method;
        @JsonProperty("substitution_data")
        private List<String> substitutionData;
        private List<Map<String,Object>> headers;
        private List<Map<String,Object>> params;
        private Map<String,Object> response;
    }
}
```

i use snakeYaml resolve this document,like this: see https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-type-safe-collections

```
@Test
public void test4(){
    Constructor constructor = new Constructor(List.class);//Car.class is root
    TypeDescription carDescription = new TypeDescription(List.class);
   // carDescription.putListPropertyType("null",MappingField.class);
    constructor.addTypeDescription(carDescription);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
    final Object load = 
    yaml.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test1.yml"));

    assertNotNull("load");
}
```

when it run ,it return the `List<Object>`,what will i do something to let it return `List<MappingField>`?
how to add java generics "MappingFields" into the list collection?

note: my yaml root is a List

Comment: have you tried this?

final List<MappingField> load = 
yaml.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test1.yml"));

Comment: i had tried this, it could return LIst<LinkedHashMap>,  like this:
`final List load = (List<MappingField>) yaml.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.yml"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<MappingFields> load = 
(List<MappingFields>) yaml.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test1.yml"));
```

will work if you put an extra tag into YAML

```
- !!your.package.MappingFields
  code: code1
...
```